# VB: Add a space after a specific character into a string if it does not already have one

Tags: vb.net

I want all of my strings to be formatted consistently. It is grabbing values from the database and sometimes there are not spaces after colons, but there should be. My goal is to add a space after a colon (:) if there isn't one already. I would prefer to do this without regex, but I am open to any solutions! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Apologies I read the title as VBA, have updated now.

Here is a nice simple solution for you.

Replace everything with a Colon and a space with just a Colon meaning all Colons no longer have a space regardless of weather they did or not initially.

Then Replace all Colons with a Colon and a Space:

```
Dim value1 As String = "Hello:World"
value1 = value1.Replace(": ", ":").Replace(":", ": ")
```

Comment: I don't know why this is down-voted. It's the simplest solution. I'd even just go `value1 = value1.Replace(":", ": ").Replace(":  ", ": ");`.

Comment: It's because I initially posted a VBA solution having misread the title which is VB: Add.... :) Thanks for the upvote to counter it :).

Comment: Also, your solution modified the value. Lets say, value is `"Format (key:value): "`. Output here will be `"Format (key: value): "`

Comment: Am i missing something here? I have read the OP a number of times now and I can't see where it gives that directive?

Comment: In this case you have a fine solution

Answer (score 0):

I can't say it's the most elegant.  And its performance is not optimized, though using `String.IndexOf` should in general be faster than looping over every character.  But being a brute force solution, it sure doesn't use regex.  ;)

Besides regex, I'm sure there's a cute one-line solution using LINQ, but it's probably hard to read and maintain.  Someone is welcome to post that for comparison.

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(EnsureSpaceAfterColon("first: second:asdf third::"))
        'prints:
        '"first: second: asdf third: : "
    End Sub

    Public Function EnsureSpaceAfterColon(input As String) As String
        Dim colon As Char = CChar(":")
        Dim space As Char = CChar(" ")
        Dim returnString As String = String.Copy(input) 'leave the original alone

        Dim index As Integer = input.IndexOf(colon)
        While index > -1 'String.IndexOf returns -1 if the index is not found

            'if the index is the last index, there is no space, so add it
            'or else if the Char at the next index is not a space, make it so
            If index = returnString.Length - 1 OrElse returnString.Chars(index + 1) <> space Then
                returnString = returnString.Insert(index + 1, space)
            End If

            'get the next index
            index = returnString.IndexOf(colon, index + 1)
        End While

        Return returnString
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        
        dim nospace as string = EnsureSpace("xxx:")
        dim space as string = EnsureSpace("xxx: ")
        Console.WriteLine("|" + nospace + "|")
        Console.WriteLine("|" + space + "|")
    End Sub
    private function EnsureSpace(val as string)
        dim temp as string = val.trim
        return temp.padright(temp.length + 1)
    end function

    ' OR
    private function EnsureSpace1(val as string)
        return val.substring(0, val.LastIndexOf(":") + 1) + " "
    end function

End Module
```

> |xxx: |
> |xxx: |

Answer (score 0):

Three different approaches (all different from the other answers)...pick your poison:

(1) Using a helper Iterator function and String.Join():

```
Public Function AddSpaceAfterColons(ByVal input As String) As String
    Return String.Join("", ColonHelper(input))
End Function

Public Iterator Function ColonHelper(ByVal input As String) As IEnumerable(Of Char)
    Dim lastCh As Nullable(Of Char)
    For Each ch As Char In input
        If lastCh.HasValue AndAlso lastCh.Value = ":"c AndAlso Not (ch = " "c) Then
            Yield " "c
        End If
        Yield ch
        lastCh = ch
    Next
    If lastCh.HasValue AndAlso lastCh.Value = ":"c Then
        Yield " "c
    End If
End Function
```

(2) Walking backwards through a StringBuilder:

```
Public Function AddSpaceAfterColons(ByVal input As String) As String
    Static colon As Char = ":"c
    Static space As Char = " "c
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(input)
    For i As Integer = sb.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If sb(i) = colon Then
            If i = (sb.Length - 1) OrElse sb(i + 1) = space Then
                sb.Insert(i + 1, space)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```

(3) Using String.Split() and a StringBuilder:

```
Public Function AddSpaceAfterColons(ByVal input As String) As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim parts() As String = input.Split(":")
    sb.Append(parts(0))
    For i As Integer = 1 To parts.Length - 1
        sb.Append(":")
        If Not parts(i).StartsWith(" ") Then
            sb.Append(" ")
        End If
        sb.Append(parts(i))
    Next
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```